# Listing the terms of a Taxonomy Vocabulary in a Tree structure using Views

Tags: views, routes, taxonomy-terms

I am on drupal7. I am trying to list all the terms of a vocabulary in a view. However the Taxonomy vocabulary has multilevel categories and subcategories.

> Is there any module to Show the list in a view so that Initially
>   **Parents** will be displayed, then when **hovered or clicked** on parent all its **child terms** are displayed, if **hovered** or
>   **clicked** on child its **sub-child** are shown.

I want to display the list in the sidebar first or in the header part of the front page .

Example:

Similar to the style how categories in [Flipkart](http://www.flipkart.com/) are displayed.

Any help!

Comment: You should check taxonomy_tree_select and hierarchical_select modules .

Comment: Though taxonomy_tree_select is not released for Drupal 7, there is another module https://drupal.org/project/term_reference_tree
Thanks @user13198 thanks a lot . I will try this

Answer (score 2):

[Taxonomy menu](https://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu) module you are looking for and also you can integrate with views, 
See the demo [here](http://taxonomymenu.davidstoline.com/)

> - Custom Menu per vocabulary
> - Uses the default taxonomy term path or custom paths
> - Integrate with Views
> - Integrate with Pathauto: use URL/path aliases
> - Does not interfere with other menu modules